# Access values after form-pre-filling (with Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have one form for saving and editing records. On clicking on a record, the form should be filled with the data. After filling, I want to do some UI actions (call jQuery Plugin etc.).

The pre-filling works, but when I'm trying to access the values, it works only at the second click. On the first click, the values are empty or the ones from the record clicked before.

This action is stored in the controller:

```
edit: function(id) {

  var _this = this;

  // prefill form for editing
  var customer = this.store.find('customer', id).then(function(data) {
    _this.set('name',data.get('name'));
    _this.set('number',data.get('number'));
    _this.set('initial',data.get('initial'));
    _this.set('description',data.get('description'));
    _this.set('archived',data.get('archived'));

    // store user for save action
    _this.set('editedRecordID',id);
    _this.set('isEditing',true);

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      console.log(this.value)
    });

  });

},
```

I need a generic way to check if the input field is empty, because I want to include this nice UI effect: http://codepen.io/aaronbarker/pen/tIprm

## **Update**

I tried to implement this in a View, but now I get always the values from the record clicked before and not from the current clicked element:

**View**

```
Docket.OrganizationCustomersView = Ember.View.extend({

  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      console.log(this.value)
    });
  }.observes('controller.editedRecordID')

});
```

**Controller**

```
Docket.OrganizationCustomersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  /* ... */    

  isEditing: false,
  editedRecordID: null,

  actions: {

    /* ... */

    edit: function(id) {

      var _this = this;

      // prefill form for editing
      var customer = this.store.find('customer', id).then(function(data) {
        _this.set('name',data.get('name'));
        _this.set('number',data.get('number'));
        _this.set('initial',data.get('initial'));
        _this.set('description',data.get('description'));
        _this.set('archived',data.get('archived'));

        // store user for save action
        _this.set('editedRecordID',id);
        _this.set('isEditing',true);
      });

    },

    /* ... */

});
```

## **Update 2**

OK, I think I misunderstood some things.

At first, my expected console output should be:

```
1.
2.
3.
```

but is:

```
1.
3.
2.
```

Secondly: I can use any name, even `foobar`, for the observed method in my view. **Why?**

**Controller**

```
edit: function(id) {

  var _this = this;

  // prefill form for editing
  var customer = this.store.find('customer', id).then(function(data) {
    _this.set('name',data.get('name'));
    _this.set('number',data.get('number'));
    _this.set('initial',data.get('initial'));
    _this.set('description',data.get('description'));
    _this.set('archived',data.get('archived'));

    console.log('1.')

    // store user for save action
    _this.set('editedRecordID',id);
    _this.set('isEditing',true);

    console.log('2.')

  });

},
```

**View**

```
Docket.OrganizationCustomersView = Ember.View.extend({

  foobar: function() {

    console.log('3.')

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      console.log(this.value)
    });
  }.observes('controller.editedRecordID')

});
```

## **Update 3**

I think I "figured it out" (but I don't know why):

```
Docket.OrganizationCustomersView = Ember.View.extend({
  movePlaceholder: function() {

    $('input[type="text"], textarea').bind("checkval",function() {
      var $obj = $(this);    
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($obj.val());
      },0);

  }.observes('controller.editedRecordID')
});
```

`setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 0);` does the trick. But why?!

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I would have to paste half the application to get this working in a fiddle :) Also, I think it's a quite generic question, isn't it? (At least after my updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert use that jquery code in a [component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html), this is the best way to create a reusable view, without putting ui logic in controllers, routers etc.

**Template**

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/float-label">
    <div class="field--wrapper">
      <label >{{title}}</label>
      {{input type="text" placeholder=placeholder value=value}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

**FloatLabelComponent**

```
App.FloatLabelComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  onClass: 'on',
  showClass: 'show',
  checkval: function() {
    var label = this.label();
    if(this.value !== ""){
      label.addClass(this.showClass);
    } else {
      label.removeClass(this.showClass);
    }
  },
  label: function() {
    return this.$('input').prev("label");
  },
  keyUp: function() {    
    this.checkval();
  },
  focusIn: function() {    
    this.label().addClass(this.onClass);
  },
  focusOut: function() {    
    this.label().removeClass(this.onClass);
  }
});
```

Give a look in that jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ILuveKIv/3/edit